# Syncing 2 local SQL Server databases over WCF service in between

Tags: sql-server, wcf, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to sync 2 SQL Server databases. The scenario is that I have 2 PCs which have identical SQL Server database (both databases have the same structure and schema) and connected to the internet.

Now, I want to have a simple Windows application developed in C# and installed on both PC that may have a `'Sync'` command button and clicking on that it calls a WCF service hosted on a web server which then sync data in both databases.

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at merge replications or maybe better Sync Framework 2.1.  Using WCF is not the way you want to go.

Comment: Will merge replication work if I don't have static IP on both PC i.e. the IP will be dynamically changing and the windows application access the internet anonymously.

Comment: Merge replication will work with dynamic DNS (afraid.org) as would sync framework.